# Which Node packages are used for Ethereum classic's (ETC) transaction implementation?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ether

I want to send ETC from one account to another i.e how to do the transaction, signature in testnet environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use web3 ([js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) or [python](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py) or anything else) to work with ETC.

Ethereum and Ethereum Classic nodes share the same JSON-RPC API.